# Does returning a reference extend its lifetime too?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, rvalue-reference, lifetime

AFAIK, in the following code the lifetime of the reference `ro1` is extended till the end of the scope (function `g()`):

```
class Some {
  // Implementation here
};
Some f() {
  return Some(/* constructor parameters here*/);
}
void g() {
  Some&& ro1 = f();
  // ro1 lives till the end of this function
}
```

How about returning this reference? Will the object still live in `g1()`, or will it be destructed upon the exit from `h()`?

```
Some&& h() {
  Some&& ro1 = f();
  // Code skipped here
  return std::forward<Some>(ro1);
}

void g1() {
  Some&& ro2 = h();
  // Is ro2 still refering to a valid object?
}
```

Comment: No life extension for your second snippet.

Comment: **If** it was `std::forward<T>` then a move construction can be expected. But in your second snippet, **since** it is an `std::forward<T&&>`, thus it avoids any construction & leaves a dangling reference

Comment: No when `g` returns the local temporary is destroyed and you are left with a dangling reference.  Also I thought reference extension was only for const ref not rvalue ref - am I missing something, did this change in C++1z?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How about returning this reference? Will the object still live in `g1()`

No. Lifetime extension is something that happens only one time. The temporary returned from `f()` is bound to the reference `ro1` and its lifetime is extended for the lifetime of that reference. `ro1`'s lifetime ends at the end of `h()`, so any use of `ro2` in `g1()` is a dangling reference.

In order for this to work, you need to deal with values:

```
Some h() {
  Some ro1 = f();
  // Code skipped here
  return ro1;
}
```

Note that RVO still applies here.